# mgcv random effects - extracting estimates and plots

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, random-effects

I am using [mgcv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) to fit GAMs with random effects, e.g.:

```
gam_fit <- gam(y ~ s(age) + s(region, bs='re'), 
               data = my_data, 
               method = 'REML')
```

See [Gavin Simpson's excellent post about using random effects in GAMs with mgcv](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2021/02/02/random-effects-in-gams/).

Two questions:

1. How to extract estimates of the random effects ? I found [extract_ranef()](https://m-clark.github.io/gammit/reference/extract_ranef.html) in a separate package, but maybe `mgcv` has its own method ?
2. In `plot(gam_fit)`, what is being plotted in the `effects` vs `Gaussian quantiles` plot ? How should these plots be used ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to extract estimates of the random effects ? I found extract_ranef() in a separate package, but maybe mgcv has its own method ?

You can use `coef(gam_fit)`, but this will also include the coefficients for the spline basis of `s(age)`. So to recover only those, I would use:

```
coefs <- coef(gam_fit)
coefs[grep("s(region)", names(coefs), fixed=TRUE)]
```

> In plot(gam_fit), what is being plotted in the effects vs Gaussian quantiles plot? How should these plots be used?

On the *x*-axis, it shows the gaussian quantiles; these reflect the values of a standard normally distributed variable. On the *y*-axis, it shows the predicted values of the random intercept. For mixed-effects models, these are assumed to follow a normal distribution. Thus, any deviation of the points from the straight line indicate a deviation from what would be expected for a normal distribution. If points on the left-most part of the *x*-axis go below the straight line, this indicates that some predicted random intercepts have lower values than would be expected for a normal distribution. If points on the right-most part of the *x*-axis go below the straight line, this indicates some predicted random intercepts have higher values than what would be expected for a normal distribution. If you observe both (or both go above and below the straight line, respectively) this indicates that the kurtosis or thickness of the tail(s) is different than for a normal distribution. I'd expect that such deviations would mostly affect inference and predictive accuracy only to a much lesser extent.